# Flann in OpenCV - unsupported distance types

Tags: python, opencv, knn, flann, opencv3.1

I am trying knn search using opencv3.1 and python 3.5.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

vectors = np.random.random([100,15]).astype(np.float32)
idx = cv2.flann.Index(vectors, {'algorithm':2}, distType=3)

[Out]: cv2.error: /opencv-3.1.0/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:403: error: (-5) Unknown/unsupported distance type in function build
```

It appears to me, [miniflann.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp) only supports `distType=1` or `distType=2` as input. Does opencv's python API always uses miniflann? Or is there way to use all [flann functionalities](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d8c/namespacecvflann.html#a4e3e6c98d774ea77fd7f0045c9bc7817) (different `algorithm` and different `distance` type) from python?